# Introductory resources on Computational Learning Theory

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, lg.learning, survey, books

Recently I've been reading a decent number of CoLT papers. Although I don't struggle with the individual papers (at least not more than I usually struggle with other theory papers), I don't feel I have a good broad grasp of the field as a whole.

**Is there a standard text, surveys, or lecture notes for introducing CoLT at the graduate level?**

I have a basic Theory A background, but no specific knowledge of Machine Learning or Statistics. I am mostly interested in things like PAC-learning and learning automata, and less interested in things like Bayesian inference and VC theory.

#### Related questions

- [Resource / book for recent advances in statistical learning theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/9027/1037)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some material more recent than Kearns and Vazirani, you could check out Rocco Servedio's lecture notes for [Advanced Topics in Computational Learning Theory](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Teaching/S12/), or the notes from [Sasha Rakhlin's class](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~rakhlin/courses/stat928/stat928_notes.pdf).

Comment: The first option looks great, are Rakhlin's notes accessible to someone without a statistics background?

Comment: Yes, they should be.

Answer (score 7):

[Kearns and Vazirani](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=7334) is maybe a bit old, but good introduction.

Comment: thanks! Is there a good survey of post-1994 results to compliment this book?